# Why i must copy Bundle resource to main project to use image in a framework?

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, frameworks

Now I have an SDK project which embedded in an main project ,and I want to use the image source in the bundle which in the SDK project ,here is my method:

```
    let bdpath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "AltynBankResource", ofType: "bundle")
    print("bundlePath:\(bdpath)")
    let bd = Bundle(path: bdpath ?? "")
   print("bundle:\(bd)")
    let img = UIImage.init(named: "ic_bg1", in: bd, compatibleWith: nil)
    print("img:\(img)")
```

and it does't work . until I copy the bundle source to the main project.

but I don't understand why, I'm not using the image in the main project , but in the SDK file . why I must copy the bundle source to main project to use it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that you are using the Main Bundle with `Bundle.main` this will take the bundle of your app.

I assume that piece of code is inside your SDK. What I usually do is getting the bundle for the SDK with `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]` in objective-C.

In swift3.x it is:

`Bundle(for: type(of: self))`

but I cant provide you with an example of swift because I haven't used this line of code in swift.

Hope this helps.